# Getting error 2003 when trying to connect to MySQL server after reboot

Tags: mysql

i have installed MySQL server 5.0 was using it for some days. i was working on some project. suddenly m getting an Error 2003 Can't connect To MySQL server after rebooting my laptop. Previously it worked well. each time i reboot my laptop i need to reconfigure my server instance to connect to MySQL server. I am not getting what is going wrong. i am using net-beans 7.0.1. I also checked task manager to see all running process after rebooting, i came to know that mysqld-nt.exe was not running. after i reconfigure my server instance it started.. Please suggest me something. its really urgent. i have my project demo with in two three days.. 
if poss reply me on my email id adeshbora@gmail.com

Comment: in Services.msc, is the MySQL service configured to Start Automatically? Error 2003 is no response from server. You can try a few things here: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Error2003-CantConnectToMySQLServer

Answer (score 0):

Thought id add my comment as an answer seeing as it solved the OP problem:

MySQL must be running to be able to connect to it. You can find it in Services.msc, and be sure it is set to 'Start Automatically'.

Error 2003 = 'No response from the server'. So be sure the MySQL service is running.
Some helpful tips can be found here:

[forge.mysql.com/wiki/Error2003-CantConnectToMySQLServer](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Error2003-CantConnectToMySQLServer)

Comment: I wrote that Error 2003 guide back in 2006.  Recently, MySQL Forge was merged into Oracle's technical wiki, and my old article has been moved to https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Errors